# Drawing a folder icon with CSS

Tags: css

I'm playing around trying to draw a simple folder icon with CSS, and this is where I'm at:

```
/* CSS */
.container {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.folder_tab, .folder {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #708090;
}
.folder_tab {
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-right: 50%;
  border-radius: 5px 15px 0 0;
}
.folder {
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 1px #CCCCCC;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="folder_tab"></div>
  <div class="folder"></div>
  text
</div>
```

Result: [image]

Is there a simpler, or more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Simpler and more elegant way: use an image. There is no point in using css for that. If you want it scalable/animatable use svg.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is my solution, if you want to use CSS3.

**HTML**

```
<div class="folder"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.folder {
    width: 150px;
    height: 105px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #708090;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.59);
}

.folder:before {
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
    background-color: #708090;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hK4pt/)** (tested in Chrome)

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is a bit old, but I bounced into this question by asking myself if there was something simple in pure CSS and minimalistic HTML to update my old tree library which uses background images for icons.

I tried by myself and I came up with something in line with the flat design which today is revolutioning cross-devices UI's:

https://jsfiddle.net/landzup/Lzjadp5r/

It is just a suggestion or a starting point, but it is amazing watching the page not losing a single pixel of resolution by zooming in as much as possible! (Just like vector graphics).

I used a brief HTML:

```
<div class="folder">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    Programming
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.folder {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 18px 0;
    font: 18px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-indent: 27px;
    line-height: 34px;
}

.folder .icon {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    background: #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; -o-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(10px) skewX(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(10px) skewX(10deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(10px) skewX(10deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(10px) skewX(10deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(10px) skewX(10deg);
}

.folder .icon::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    left: -6px;
    width: 30px; height: 21px;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    background: #ddd;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; -o-border-radius: 2px; border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(10px) skewX(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(10px) skewX(-20deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(10px) skewX(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(10px) skewX(-20deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateX(10px) skewX(-20deg);
}
</style>
```

It uses CSS 3 transformations, so you should consider your target audience to support its browsers.
Here there are CSS compatibility tables for CSS transformation:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/wQdgs/

### HTML

```
<div>text</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

div:after {
    content: " ";
    width: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0 1px #CCCCCC;
    display: block;
    background-color: #708090;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 25px;    
}

div:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 15px 0 0;
    display: block;
    background-color: #708090;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
}
```